# automating updates to Flash on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, flash

I'm searching for a scriptable/automated way to have the latest version of Flash installed on Windows XP and Windows 7 testing machines.

These machines serve testing purposes, however, because of the number of different machines we have, it is unwieldy to update them all by hand.

How can the installation of Flash be automated?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.adobe.com/licensing/

> Distribute Adobe web players
>
> Adobe provides a free license to allow
>   you to redistribute Adobe Flash®
>   Player or Adobe Shockwave® Player on
>   your company's intranet, or with your
>   software product or service. Use this
>   online application to apply for a
>   license for any or all of the Adobe
>   web players